# How to replace a particular string in rdlc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, rdlc

I just want to replace a particular text with blank space in RDLC column.

I want to replace .`aspx` with `""` in every string.

I tried writing

```
=Replace(Fields!AuditsUserActivity.Value, ".aspx", "")
```

it works for this kinda lines

```
Page Applicants.aspx viewed
```

but not for these kinda lines:

```
Data added in Inspectors.aspx
```

i.e. it removed .aspx from those lines in which .aspx appears in in-between but not for those in which .aspx appears at the end of string.

WHY ?

Comment: Help please, it has wasted my time a lot

Comment: Your expression is correct so there is a problem in your data. Maybe your `AuditsUserActivity` contains carriage return? Maybe you use a `DataColumn` in your `Dataset` that truncate the string? Try simply printing `AuditsUserActivity.Value` to see its content.

Comment: same value that i said